# Expressing the Complete Data Likelihood for Factor Analysis Model with VAR(1) errors

Tags: likelihood, factor-analysis, autoregressive, joint-distribution, lags

I am working on a model related to that below. For $t=1, 2, \ldots, T$ the vector of $N$ observations, $X_t$, is related to a vector of $K$ latent factors, $F_t$, via the observation equation
$$X_t = \Lambda F_t + u_t$$
The factors are independent standard normal random vectors, i.e.
$$F_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, \text{Id}_K)$$
The errors $u_t$ are normally distributed VAR(1) processes. In other words,
$$u_t = \Phi u_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma), \quad \Phi, \Sigma \text{ are diagonal}$$

**Question:** How should I go about obtaining the complete data likelihood $p(X_{1:T}, F_{1:T} | \Theta)$? Essentially it boils down to understanding the proper way to express $p(X_{1:T} | F_{1:T}, \Theta)$ because $p(F_{1:T} | \Theta)$ is essentially specified already.

**My Attempt**

Using the lag operator $L$ and a matrix polynomial one can represent the VAR(1) process as
$$A(L)u_t = \epsilon_t, \quad A(L) = \text{Id}_N - \Phi L$$
By applying $A(L)$ to both sides of the observation equation you can obtain a multivariate ARDL(1,1) representation
$$X_t = \Phi X_{t-1} + \Lambda F_t - \Phi \Lambda F_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
This shows that $X_t$ depends on $X_{t-1}$, $F_{t-1}$, and $F_t$, the conditional distribution is
$$X_t \,|\, X_{t-1}, F_{t-1}, F_t, \Theta \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \Phi X_{t-1} + \Lambda F_t - \Phi \Lambda F_{t-1}\,,\, \Sigma \right)$$
and now it follows that
$$p(X_{1:T} \,|\, F_{1:T}, \Theta) = \prod_{t=1}^T p(X_t \,|\, X_{t-1}, F_{t-1}, F_t, \Theta)$$
but the problem here is that I don't know how $X_0$ and $F_0$ should be treated, but I see two possibilities:

1. Treat $X_0$ and $F_0$ as known constants. If this is okay to do, then would it matter what they are set to? Can they each be set to the 0 vector?
2. Treat $X_0$ and $F_0$ as random vectors. If they are to be treated as random variables, several posts on CV seem to indicate that they should be set to their stationary distributions. If this is the proper way to treat them, then what would the stationary distribution for $X_0$ be?

I imagine that the mean of the stationary distribution should be 0. That leaves me to find the variance of the stationary distribution. I try to solve the equation $\text{Var}(X_t) = \text{Var}(X_{t-1}) \,\forall t$. Starting with the far LHS I have
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X_t) &= \text{Var}(\Phi X_{t-1} + \Lambda F_t - \Phi \Lambda F_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) \\
&= \text{Var}(\Phi u_{t-1} + \Lambda F_t + \epsilon_t) \\
&= \text{Var}(\Phi u_{t-1}) + \text{Var}(\Lambda F_t) + \text{Var}(\epsilon_t)
\end{align}
where the last equality is because I think it's reasonable to assume these variables are all independent of one another. In the last equality, I can find each of those variances, so then I'd allow the stationary distribution of $X_0$ to be normal with variance as whatever comes about from the last equation above.

I hope my question makes sense. If you spot anything that needs clarifying, then please let me know.